# How to troubleshoot a double loaded object in mef

Tags: .net, prism, mef

I have an issue where my object is loaded twice in MEF.  So MEF returns two of my object, which causes my entire program to crash because I am expecting only one.

How can I trace through/step through my program to figure out where the objects are being double registered?

I have an Export tag on the class.  I assume this accounts for one of the instances.

I am using prism and the object that appears twice is the Shell view.

TDL having trouble figuring out how to debug mef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compose the object, MEF will raise a [CompositionException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.compositionexception.aspx) when it tries to compose the `[Import]` matching the type.  The exception details of the CompositionException are very detailed, and will give you the potential matches.

Look at the full text of the CompositionException - it should provide you with all of the "matches" that are occurring for a given import, allowing you to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd venture to say you loaded the Assembly twice into the AggregateCatalog somehow.